# Target CSS child selector created by in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have styles like this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: 5
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  active: {
    // here I want to target the 'container' className I created above like
    '& .container': {
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
  }
});
```

I want to target the `container` className I created inside of the `active` className. The above won't work because in the DOM, MUI will [generate](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#using-the-dev-tools) a unique name so I won't be targeting the right class. Wasn't able to find any SO answer or blog or documentation addressing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ rulename` is used for this purpose. [Here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) is the documentation of it on Material-UI.

[CSS in JS](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.5.1#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) documentation also explains this feature.

```
container: {
  //other styles
},
active: {
  "& $container": {
    background: "green",
    color: "#fff"
  }
}
```

Here one thing which is important that for referencing 'container`rule, it should be defined in the rules object. trying to use`"& $container`without defining the`container`rule inside the`makeStyles` will not work.

Here is the working demo:

[image: Edit nested rulename selector]

Answer (score 2):

You can refer using `$`

You will have to modify your DOM little bit such that the `active` className is not the parent of `container`. Instead add the `active` className to the `conatiner` element itself.

so your css style might look like below

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: 5
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    
    '&$active': {
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
  },
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for [$rulename](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet)

How to Use $ruleName to reference a local rule within the same style sheet

In your case i think the solution would be

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: 5
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  active: {
    .container: {
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
  }
});


   Which should compile to
```

`.root.container.active{}`
and on the target tag taking a example of button here

```
 <Button
  classes={{
    root: classes.root,
    container: classes.container,
    active: classes.active,
  }}>
```

Havent worked with MUI yet but even in vue or react the way this is achived is by setting a dynamic name on the tag that is targeted via script.